# DNS request for google.com returns different a_record at different time even the name-server is same each time

Tags: dns

First I requested to resolve A_Record for domain from [ns3.google.com]216.239.36.10 and found 216.58.220.14

In next turn again I requested to resolve A_Record for domain from [ns3.google.com]216.239.36.10 and found 216.58.203.174.

So, my question is why same name-server for google.com is returning different a_record?
Is there any way to get all a_record mapped agains google.com?

Comment: This is done for balancing load across servers and also routing you to geographically close ones (Mumbai). I don't know if there is a way to get all A records, that's a more interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below url to find all available records any given point of time.

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/